# AsynkTask is interrupted by app after API 19

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my application I am using AsynkTask(private inner class) to send a "post" request, then put result in to the array and return this array back. All of this happening in the doInBackground().

AsynkTask is called in onCreate method by `asyncTask.execute().get();`.

So the problem is that all of this perfectly working on Android versions under API19. But in versions after API19 the application doesn't wait for the result from `asyncTask.execute().get();`.

Thanks in advance. 
onCreate:

```
        MyAsyncTask asyncTask;
        asyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();
        values = asyncTask.execute().get(); // Not waiting for the result
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            listArr.add(values[i]); // So it gives me exception that "values" is null
        }
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, items, imgs, values);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it doesn't work this way with AsyncTask.

This won't really wait for your result:

```
values = asyncTask.execute().get();
```

With an AsyncTask, you call the `execute()` method, and then you have the `onPostExecuted` or `onPostCancelled` methods, depending wether the AsyncTask was completed or cancelled. There you can hand the result back to the caller.

As the name `AsyncTask` already implies, it is *asynchronous*, which means *it won't wait*.

I strongly suggest you read the [AsyncTask docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) from Google...

Comment: Thanks, but I already know it. With execute().get() I can get results back. It works fine on all api's under 19. I also implemented this in my another app and it worked fine

Comment: Well, you wanted to know why it's not working, and I told you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library and get data from server easily and fast.   https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative, when your AsyncTask finishes it calls a method in your Main with the data.

In your AsyncTask :

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<YourData> result) {
    ((MainActivity) activity).updateUI(result);
}
```

And in MainActivity :

```
public void updateUI(List<YourData> result) {
    // process your data
}
```